# Keyboard Device manager hidden

Tags: keyboard, device-manager, hid, standards, ps2-keyboard

when im fixing my keyboard (HID)in device manager.

My keyboard category in device manager are go to hidden devices I saw it by clicking view and checking showhidden files , and it cant detect my keyboard and it shows like this

when i open keyboard categories it shows many lists of HID Keyboard Device and Standard PS/2 Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Is your keyboard working? I mean check if the hardware is faulty by connecting it to some other PC. Try installing drivers from the manufacturer's website.